# How to find what is between two text points in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have this:

```
<div id="wrapper">
 <pre class="highlight">
    $(function(){
    // hide all links except for the first
    $('ul.child:not(:first)').hide();
    $("a.slide:first").css("background-color","#FF9900");

    /*
        The comment goes here.
    */

  </pre>
</div>
```

With jQuery, I want to find what is in between:

```
    /*
        The comment goes here.
    */
```

Including those comment signs. So it should return:

```
    /*
        The comment goes here.
    */
```

How to do that, how to find text between two points?

Comment: You mean from within a `script` tag?

Comment: @Pekka: I think so because jquery will go in script on a page. Even if not, how to simply find what is in between two text points not just in script tag.

Comment: I see. Probably something along the lines of a regular expression on the `innerText` of the `body`... Interested to see what comes up.

Comment: @@Pekka: Basically i want grab those comment blocks and **color** them a bit differently than rest of the code. Yes, hope there is a solution soon :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the fastest and ugliest way to do this is like this :

```
var t = $('pre.highlight').html();
$('pre.highlight').html(
   t.replace(/(\/\*[.\S\s]*\*\/)/,'<span class="comment">$1</span>')
);
```

Maybe could replace open search and closure search with vars

```
var s = "\/\*";
var c = "\*\/";
var rexp = RegExp( s + "[.\S\s]*" + c )
```

Dunno, just brainstorming

Comment: +1: That's good, let me see if there are more options. Thanks